# Predeclared class instance tracks the number of regular instances

Tags: object-oriented, vba

#### Predeclared class instance tracks the number of regular instances

In VBA, predeclared class instances can act as [object factories](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/04/24/factories-parameterized-object-initialization/), and in general, it makes sense to keep this instance stateless. However, I needed to count non-default instances and execute reset code whenever all of them were destroyed. I came up with the following code to have the *predeclared* class instance do this job (code below includes attributes definition, factory, constructor, and instance counting):

**DbManager.cls**

```vb
'@Folder "DbManager"
'@ModuleDescription "Top database API class. Abstract factory for DbConnection."
'@PredeclaredId
Option Explicit

Private Type TDbManager
    Connections As Scripting.Dictionary
    InstanceCount As Long
End Type
Private this As TDbManager


Public Function Create() As DbManager
    Dim Instance As DbManager
    Set Instance = New DbManager
    Instance.Init
    Set Create = Instance
End Function

Friend Sub Init()
    Set this.Connections = New Scripting.Dictionary
    this.Connections.CompareMode = TextCompare
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    If Me Is DbManager Then
        this.InstanceCount = 0
    Else
        DbManager.InstanceAdd
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    DbManager.InstanceDel
End Sub

Public Property Get InstanceCount() As Long
    If Me Is DbManager Then
        InstanceCount = this.InstanceCount
    Else
        InstanceCount = DbManager.InstanceCount
    End If
End Property

Public Property Let InstanceCount(ByVal Value As Long)
    If Me Is DbManager Then
        this.InstanceCount = Value
    Else
        DbManager.InstanceCount = Value
    End If
End Property

Public Sub InstanceAdd()
    If Me Is DbManager Then
        this.InstanceCount = this.InstanceCount + 1
    Else
        DbManager.InstanceCount = DbManager.InstanceCount + 1
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub InstanceDel()
    If Me Is DbManager Then
        this.InstanceCount = this.InstanceCount - 1
        If this.InstanceCount = 0 Then
            '''' CLEANUP WHEN ALL REGULAR INSTANCES DESTROYED
        End If
    Else
        DbManager.InstanceCount = DbManager.InstanceCount - 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a highly redacted version of the `DbManager` class as it seems to have no 'Db' behavior and no external dependencies.  As a consequence, setting the PredeclaredId = True, on the surface, seems unnecessary as there are no parameters in the `Create` function.  That said, I suspect there really *are* `Create` parameters in the non-redacted version.  Assuming the code works as intended and the above assumptions are also true, a few comments came to mind regarding the code.

**Default instances**

When the PredeclaredId attribute of a VBA ClassModule is set to `True`, the class is *like* a static Class in C# and can offer immediately callable methods.  This setup provides for a clever workaround for VBA's lack of parameterized constructors.  Even so, this default instance is *still* an 'instance' of the `DbManager`.

In this case the goal of counting instances is complicated by the presence of a default instance.  The frequent use of `If-Else-End If` constructs within the `DbManager` class to discern the Default instance versus the 'Regular' instances highlights this problem.  Having the `PredeclaredId` attribute set to `True` is getting in the way.

Further, it is unusual for an object to be responsible for tracking how many of 'itself' have been created/released.

As it relates to the code provided, it looks as though the `DbManager` has four responsibilities:

1. DbManager Db related interactions.  Again, it is assumed that the post is highly redacted and `DbManager` has  functionality beyond what is shown.
2. Creating DbManager instances - currently uses the parameterize-able creation mechanism
3. Tracking instance creation and deletion
4. Resetting 'stuff' whenever the number of DbManager instances 'out in the wild' exceed '0' and then returns to '0'.

It would seem that all these collateral duties (#2-#4) can be addressed by applying the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) with a bit more rigor.

So, one approach to re-organizing the responsibilities:

1. `DbManager`: Set the `PredeclaredId` attribute to `False`. Let this class focus just on itself.  All instances (however created) are 'Regular' instances.  This eliminates all the `If-Else-End If` business.
2. `DbManagerProvider`: Is the object that replaces all the previous default instance `DbManager.Create()` calls.  The object provides fully initialized `DbManager` instances on demand.  Setting the `PredeclaredId` attribute to `True` for this class could be appropriate.  It is likely that this class should be a singleton in your application.
3. `InstanceCountTracker`: Injected into each `DbManager` instance by the `DbManagerProvider` to support the `InstanceDel` method call when `Class_Terminate()` is invoked on a `DbManager` instance.
4. `IDbResetter`: Handles reset operations when the `DbManager` instance count reaches zero.

A bit more about `IDBResetter`: The 'Reset' responsibility is provided as an interface so that it can be swapped out for different 'Reset' implementations.  It is my assumption that the `Reset` operation interacts with the same 'Db' dependencies/resources as a `DbManager`.  Since the `DbManagerProvider` *knows* how to create a `DbManager`, it also *knows* about all the associated dependencies.  So, the default `IDbResetter` implementation is provided by the `DbManagerProvider`.

**Testing - Dependency Injection**

To support testing, the `DbManagerProvider` can be injected with another `IDbResetter` implementation to provide with each new `DbManager` instance.  In the context of testing, the injected implementation would provide isolation to/from the 'Db' resources and probaby does nothing when 'Reset' is called.

An example of how distributing the various responsibilities *could* be implemented.

**DbManager.cls**
The `DbManager` class does nothing but *manage the Db* now.  Without the `PredeclaredId` attribute set to `True`, all instances are 'equal'.  Instance tracking is provided by the injected `IInstanceCountTracker` interface.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TDbManager
    Connections As Scripting.Dictionary
    InstanceTracker As IInstanceCountTracker
End Type

Private this As TDbManager

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.Connections = New Scripting.Dictionary
    this.Connections.CompareMode = TextCompare
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
On Error Resume Next
    this.InstanceTracker.InstanceDel
End Sub

Public Property Get InstanceTracker() As IInstanceCountTracker
    InstanceTracker = this.InstanceTracker
End Property
Public Property Set InstanceTracker(ByVal RHS As IInstanceCountTracker)
    Set this.InstanceTracker = RHS
End Property
```

**DbManagerProvider**
The `DbManagerProvider` handles instance creation and initialization.  It also provides the 'Reset' implementation by implementing the `IDbResetter` interface.

```
Option Explicit

Implements IDbResetter

Private Type TDbManagerProvider
    InstanceTracker As IInstanceCountTracker
End Type

Private this As TDbManagerProvider

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set this.InstanceTracker = New InstanceCountTracker
    
    'This object provides the default 'Reset' implementation
    Set this.InstanceTracker.Resetter = Me
End Sub

Public Function CreateDbManager() As DbManager
    Set CreateDbManager = New DbManager
    this.InstanceTracker.InstanceAdd
    
    Set CreateDbManager.InstanceTracker = this.InstanceTracker
End Function

Private Sub IDbResetter_Reset()
    '''' CLEANUP WHEN ALL REGULAR INSTANCES DESTROYED
End Sub

'Allow for injecting a Fake/Stub IDbResetter.  Use to isolate/ignore necessary Db objects during testing
Public Sub InjectResetter(ByVal pResetter As IDbResetter)
    Set this.InstanceTracker.Resetter = pResetter
End Sub
```

**InstanceCountTracker**
`InstanceCountTracker` encapsulates the instance counting process and the criteria/logic for invoking the 'Reset' process.  Contains an `IDbResetter` reference to invoke the 'Reset' process.

```
Option Explicit

Implements IInstanceCountTracker

Private Type TInstanceCountTracker
    InstanceCount As Long
    ResetOnNextZero As Boolean
    Resetter As IDbResetter
End Type

Private this As TInstanceCountTracker

Private Sub IInstanceCountTracker_InstanceAdd()
    this.InstanceCount = this.InstanceCount + 1
    this.ResetOnNextZero = True
End Sub

Private Sub IInstanceCountTracker_InstanceDel()
    
    If this.InstanceCount = 0 Then
        'TODO: Handle/Raise an error
    End If
    
    this.InstanceCount = this.InstanceCount - 1
        
    If this.ResetOnNextZero And this.InstanceCount = 0 Then
        this.ResetOnNextZero = False
        
        this.Resetter.Reset
    End If
End Sub

Private Property Get IInstanceCountTracker_Resetter() As IDbResetter
    Set IInstanceCountTracker_Resetter = this.Resetter
End Property

Private Property Set IInstanceCountTracker_Resetter(ByVal RHS As IDbResetter)
    Set this.Resetter = RHS
End Property
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I indeed removed all business logic to focus on the topic. In the code, I try to follow design patterns illustrated by the RDVBA blog. I learned about this implementation of the factory pattern in VBA using predeclared instances from there. The full version of the DbManager class is a top-level API class. It takes care of the environment (by calling a class that loads a custom dll module necessary for db functionality) and generates/manages DbConnection classes. It has only one function directly involving a database - backing up the database.

Comment: The fact that VBA does not have class objects (only instances) does make certain things more complicated. I use the factory pattern (VBA style), and DbManagerProvider implements the abstract factory pattern. Both of them have pros and cons, and I use both. Regular instances are responsible for #1, and in languages supporting class objects, such as Python, classes perform function #2, but in VBA, #2 must be implemented explicitly, and the code goes in the same class module when the factory pattern is used (a bit of a hack), which is what I aim at with DbManager.

Comment: Instance counting is another hack, which I came up with to address a few other VBA limitations (this topic is a part of a separate CR question). I agree that DbManager has multiple responsibilities, and proposed refactoring has certain advantages. On the other hand, these responsibilities have a common theme, focused on the preparation of the environment for database interaction and clean-up at the exit. Except for the backup routine, other DB-related functions are implemented in underlying classes.